# AVX-512 - Debugging application with Intel SDE not working

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, intel, avx512

I am trying to debug AVX-512 instructions on an emulated CPU using [Intel® Software Development Emulator](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-software-development-emulator.html) but it doesn't work as desired after setting a breakpoint. I followed this blog post: [Debugging Emulated Code on Linux*](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/debugging-applications-with-intel-sde.html#Linux)

In window #1:

```sh
~$ g++ -g -O0 -mavx512f main.cpp -o main # compile main.cpp file
~$ sde -debug -- ./main # enable debugging

Application stopped until continued from debugger.
Start GDB, then issue this command at the (gdb) prompt:
target remote :54105
```

In window #2

```sh
# run debugger
~$ gdb ./main 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./main...

# set target "target remote :portnumber"
(gdb) target remote :54105  
Remote debugging using :54105
warning: remote target does not support file transfer, attempting to access files from local filesystem.
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
0x00007fa7bbbcc100 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

# suspend program at main function
(gdb) break main   
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2c9c: file /home/borrow/source/repos/se-test/main.cpp, line 165.

# start program execution from the beginning of the program
(gdb) run        
The "remote" target does not support "run".  Try "help target" or
"continue".

# step to next line of code
(gdb) step        
Cannot find bounds of current function

# continue executing until next break point
(gdb) c         
Continuing.
warning: Probes-based dynamic linker interface failed.
Reverting to original interface.
[Inferior 1 (Remote target) exited normally]
```

In window #2: as you can see

`gdb run` should run a program but it doesn't work. `gdb c` should also run until the next breakpoint but executes the program and terminates. This command gives me the following warning message:

> warning: Probes-based dynamic linker interface failed.

In window #1: The program runs and ends (without stopping).

Program code looks like this:

```c
//  main.cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

const int N=64;
int64_t srcA[N] = {0};
int64_t srcB[N] = {0};
int64_t dst[N] = {0};


void foo()
{
    __m512i result,B,C;
    for ( int i=0; i<N; i+=8 ){
        B =  _mm512_loadu_si512(&srcA[i]);
        C =  _mm512_loadu_si512(&srcB[i]);
        result = _mm512_add_epi64(B,C);
        _mm512_storeu_si512(&dst[i], result);
    }
}
 
int main() {
     ...
     foo();
     ...
}
```

I tried running AVX2 code without SDE emulator using gdb and it worked. First I start it on an emulated CPU with SDE, it fails. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you run `gdb ./main` so you'd have symbols right away, before connecting to the remote?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend `alignas(64)` on your arrays; AVX-512 benefits a lot more than AVX2 from alignment.  (Like 20% slowdown from misaligned vs. only a couple % with AVX2, for looping over an array that cache-misses to DRAM.)

Comment: @PeterCordes What do you mean? I compile the main.cpp file and the -g flag produces debugging information. Then I am trying to debug this code. If your machine supports AVX 512 (or AVX2, SSE), you can try debugging without SDE. It should work. But when I debug emulated code it is not working anymore

Comment: Your GDB output like `warning: remote target does not support file transfer, attempting to access files from local filesystem.` seems to indicate that GDB didn't know what file to debug until it connected to the remote.  IDK if you'd have any different results if you told GDB what file as part of running GDB, so you can set breakpoints.  Of course you don't actually *run* the AVX-512 program inside GDB, you still use the `remote` command, but you can have already told it to set breakpoints I think.

Comment: Just tried this on my own machine with GDB 10.1 and SDE 8.33, confirmed.  Same error message.  Using `gdb ./a.out` to set breakpoints before using `target remote` doesn't help, and doesn't even make the "file transfer" warning go away.  Oh well, so much for that guess.  I'm pretty sure this used to work, that in the past I've used SDE to single-step AVX-512 code.

Comment: I also tried clang++ / lldb and it crashes too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems to be broken for PIE executables**
(confirmed on Arch GNU/Linux with GCC 10.2, GDB 10.1, SDE 8.33.)

**Build with `g++ -O2 -fno-pie -no-pie  -g -march=skylake-avx512` and everything works**.  (I had to run `gdb ./a.out` instead of bare GDB; without that it couldn't find the right file even after connecting to the remote.)

```
$ g++ -O2 -march=skylake-avx512 -no-pie -fno-pie -g  avx512.cpp
$ /opt/sde-external-8.33.0-2019-02-07-lin/sde64 -debug -- ./a.out
Application stopped until continued from debugger.
Start GDB, then issue this command at the (gdb) prompt:
  target remote :59783
```

Then in another terminal tab

```
$ gdb ./a.out
...
(gdb)   target remote :59783
warning: remote target does not support file transfer, attempting to access files from local filesystem.
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...
(No debugging symbols found in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
0x00007f4f7033b090 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401050: file avx512.cpp, line 29.
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 2 at 0x401190: file avx512.cpp, line 14.
(gdb) c
Continuing. 
Breakpoint 1, main () at avx512.cpp:23
(gdb) layout asm
(copy-paste of some of the disassembly window)
│B+ 0x401120 <_Z3foov>              xor    eax,eax
│   0x401122 <_Z3foov+2>            nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
│  >0x401128 <_Z3foov+8>            vmovdqu64 zmm1,ZMMWORD PTR [rax+0x404260]
│   0x401132 <_Z3foov+18>           add    rax,0x40
│   0x401136 <_Z3foov+22>           vpaddq zmm0,zmm1,ZMMWORD PTR [rax+0x404420]
│   0x401140 <_Z3foov+32>           vmovdqu64 ZMMWORD PTR [rax+0x404020],zmm0
│   0x40114a <_Z3foov+42>           cmp    rax,0x200
│   0x401150 <_Z3foov+48>           jne    0x401128 <_Z3foov+8>
│   0x401152 <_Z3foov+50>           vzeroupper
│   0x401155 <_Z3foov+53>           ret
(gdb) layout src
```

asm-level and source-level debugging both work fine, stepping into intrinsic "functions" in `avx512fintrin.h` and so on when using `stepi` (aka `si`).

---

Without specifying the filename separately from connecting to the remote:

```
$ gdb
(gdb)  target remote :46879
Remote debugging using :46879 warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.
0x00007f0f85830090 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

(IDK if it matters that my `.gdbinit` includes `layout reg`, the full-screen terminal TUI mode.  Nice when it works but somewhat buggy.)

---

Or as a super hacky workaround with PIE executables, I was also able to put a delay loop at the top of `main`, giving you a chance to attach and then control-C before SDE finishes executing your program.

Then I could set breakpoints and start single-stepping.  (Presumably a `sleep` or `read` system call would work).  Source-level debugging still seemed broken, but I was able to debug the asm with `layout reg`.  I used `set $rip = ...` with a copy-pasted address to get out of the `_mm_pause()` loop after attaching and hitting control-C.